# Android create sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having trouble with a simple file to create a sqlite db.
I am logging some messages that I was expecting to show in the logs if the database is created or upgraded but they are not showing.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.karim.myandoidapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String msg = "My android app log : ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(msg, "onCreate() event loading activity_home view");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.e(msg, "onCreate() event loading activity_home view");
        Context context = myandoidapp.getAppContext();
        MySQLiteHelper MySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    private class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydbnamesss";

        public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.e("DEBUG: ", "db created at " + db.getPath());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.e("DEBUG: ", "db upgraded ");
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the output that I have in my logs:

```
06-14 15:02:29.122 6644-6644/com.example.karim.myandoidapp E/My android app log :: Opening HomeActivity

    --------- beginning of system
06-14 15:02:29.141 6644-6644/com.example.karim.myandoidapp E/My android app log :: onCreate() event loading activity_home view
06-14 15:02:29.203 6644-6673/com.example.karim.myandoidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa22050c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa2203360)
06-14 15:02:29.209 6644-6673/com.example.karim.myandoidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa22050c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa2203360)
06-14 15:02:29.216 6644-6673/com.example.karim.myandoidapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa22050c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa2203360)
06-14 15:02:29.218 6644-6673/com.example.karim.myandoidapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8eeae180 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa2203ac0
```

I am adding here how I am getting the context in case it is relevant:

package com.example.karim.myandoidapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Application;

```
public class myandoidapp extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myandoidapp.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return myandoidapp.context;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onCreate` method will only be called when an attempt is made to actually get/open the database. The simple fix would be to change :-

```
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

to

```
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<< this.getReadableDatabase could also be used.  
    }
```

If you want to always have a closed db, it could be better to use :-

```
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        mydb.close();
    }
```

- There are many arguments as to whether or not you should keep opening/closing the database (personally I tend to keep it open)

Then when you instantiate the Database Helper, using `MySQLiteHelper MySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);`. An attempt is made to open the database.

Note that the `onCreate` method is only called once for the lifetime of the database, so you would only get the log messages the first time the database is opened *(you could delete the App's data or uninstall the App and this would then result in `onCreate` being called again)*.

The `onUpgrade` method would only be called when the version number is increased and again not until an attempt is made to open/get the database.

Comment: we are really close. I updated my post with the class I am getting the context with: i am getting this error message: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.karim.myandoidapp/com.example.karim.myandoidapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: change two lines `Context context = myandoidapp.getAppContext();
        MySQLiteHelper MySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);` to just `MySQLiteHelper MySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code defines a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and then instantiates it, but that's not enough to create/open a SQLite database. If I were you, I'd read up on the new library by Google called [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). It's a fantastic library that helps you create and maintain SQLite databases with far less effort than manually creating your own instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, maintaining migrations, etc...

Comment: I am doing my baby steps to learn android. I thought it is easier than learning an orm but I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Totally understandable. I promise that Room is much easier to learn that dealing with all of the low level `SQLiteOpenHelper` stuff. Been there, done that :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting this error in your Fragment. Then the reason is that:

**Don't initialize the variable outside oncreateView() method.
only initialize the variable inside the oncreateView() method.**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment 
{
  //MySQLiteHelper db =new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity()); do not initialize it here like this only declare it like below
 MySQLiteHelper db ;
 
 public SecondFragment(){}

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    db =new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity()); //Initialize it here only
  }
   }
```